# Error on import forked package using go modules

Tags: go, module

I saw some other related topics here on the stackoverflow about this and, in principle, the solution that would work for me would be to use `replace` in go.mod

So I imported it into my forked branch and put the replace in my go.mod:

```
replace github.com/jinzhu/gorm => github.com/ViniciusGabrielf/gorm v1.9.13-0.20200428193232-e86cf5f42467
```

However he still returns this error to me:

```
go: github.com/ViniciusGabrielf/gorm@v1.9.12: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: github.com/jinzhu/gorm
                but was required as: github.com / ViniciusGabrielf / gorm
```

In some other topics I saw that the solution to this error would be just the implementation of replace, but even with replace I am still having this error, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you change the module name of gorm to correspond to your "fork"?

Comment: @Volker Is it necessary to change just the go.mod file from the fork or is it necessary to change it elsewhere as well?

Comment: @Volker That was it, now it worked, thank you!

Comment: The underlying reason is that you if you "fork" a Go package or module you create a new, different package/module which has no Go-ish relation to the original module/package, the "I-am-a-fork"-relation is solely source code related but for Go it is something new (and if it declares to be the old stuff it is a lie which is taken serious.)

Comment: @Volker Got it, thanks for the clarification.